# Standalone Python app not working on friend's Mac

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, platypus

A standalone Python Tkinter app I made on my Mac and put together with Platypus works just great but when I shared it with a friend, he opened it and got a window with a bunch of gibberish. I'm assuming standalone means he doesn't need Python installed on his Mac so what's wrong? I've attached the window that pops up for my friend.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDjfp.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by "he opened it"?  How did you turn it into a "standalone" app?  There certainly are tools that can turn a Python app into a standalone executable (like pyinstaller).

Comment: Can you share more information regarding your steps to export the Tkinter app and what you got as result?

Comment: My friend got the app and right-clicked it to open it (and get past the unknown developer security message). The Platypus app is found here: https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus. I've also tried py2app and didn't get much success. As soon as he opened it, my friend got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDjfp.jpg